# Error after vagrant up

Tags: php, linux, shell, ssh, vagrant

My Vagrantfile is so configured that if I do "vagrant up" it runs a provision script which install all my desired packages. That's exactly what I'm doing but i get an error after doing "vagrant up" (for the first time)
Here's the error: 
[image]

Here's my provisions.sh code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PROJECT="foundation"
PROJECT_LOG="foundation"

MYSQL_PASSWORD="password"

set -o nounset -o errexit -o pipefail -o errtrace

error() {
   local sourcefile=$1
   local lineno=$2
   echo "ERROR at ${sourcefile}:${lineno}; Last logs:"
   grep "${PROJECT}" /var/log/syslog | tail -n 20
}

trap 'error "${BASH_SOURCE}" "${LINENO}"' ERR

oe() { "$@" 2>&1 | logger -t "${PROJECT}" > /dev/null; }
ol() { echo "[${PROJECT_LOG}] $@"; }

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ol 'Updating repository caches'
oe sudo apt-get -q -y update

ol 'Adding apt repositories'
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install python-software-properties
oe sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6

ol 'Updating repository caches (second time)'
oe sudo apt-get -q -y update

ol "Installing misc packages"
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install language-pack-nl

ol 'Installing Apache 2'
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install apache2
oe sudo systemctl restart apache2
oe sudo systemctl status apache2

ol "Installing PHP"
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 \\
  php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php-pear php5-imagick \\
  php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcached php5-ming php5-ps \\
  php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy \\
  php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl php5-xcache

ol 'Installing Sendmail'
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install sendmail

ol 'Restarting Apache 2'
oe sudo systemctl restart apache2
oe sudo systemctl status apache2

ol "Installing MySQL"
oe sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
oe sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install mysql-server mysql-client
oe sudo systemctl restart mysql
oe sudo systemctl status mysql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It complains on

```
==> default: Apr 22 01:06:22 vagrant-ubuntu-wily-64 foundation:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
==> default: Apr 22 01:06:22 vagrant-ubuntu-wily-64 foundation: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

in your Vagrantfile, make sure to set the hostname as a fully qualified domain, something like

```
config.vm.hostname = "dev.local"
```

should make the provisioning happy.

second it does not like the `\\` in your php install package

you can put everything in one line and it will work

```
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcached php5-ming php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl php5-xcache
```

it comes from the `oe` method but not sure how to handle it

Comment: Thank you very much! this is it.